# How do I avoid the initial text portion when creating a PEM certificate with openssl?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I've created my own CA with openssl. The problem I'm having is that when I sign a CSR and generate a PEM certificate with it, there is an initial text portion in the certificate where I was only want the actual encoded certificate itself.

In other words, the output certificate begins

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            9a:e2:f9:21:e1:fe:be:10:71:b0:1f:b9:7a:1b:ec:c8
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Where as I only want it to begin with:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFGzCCAwOgAwIBAgIRAJri+SHh/r4QcbAfuXob7MgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
```

Here is the command used:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in  www.example.com.csr -out www.example.com.crt -batch -extensions x509
```

From my config:

```
[x509]
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false,pathlen:0
extendedKeyUsage        = serverAuth
keyUsage                = critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign,digitalSignature
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
```

I need to do this because the certificate is not being accepted by a certain application. When I test without the initial text portion it works fine.

Comment: What kind of `initial text portion` you are talking about?

Comment: *"the actual encrypted certificate"* - the certificate is **not encrypted**. It is **only encoded** and the encoding offers no kind of protection. The information can be easily shown when using `openssl x509 -in ... -text`. So you basically want to omit information which can easily extracted from the part you need to preserve.

Comment: What about do a parser your own?

Comment: A very simple shell script in the language of your choice can strip or extract any text you want... I'm not sure this is a security question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming or development question or problem and will probably be closed, but from the man page for ca(1ssl?) or maybe openssl-ca(1) on your system (unless Windows)  or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html):

> **-notext**
> Don't output the text form of a certificate to the output file.

Although as commented it's also trivial to fix the file afterwards with standard text-handling tools; that's one of the many reasons PEM format is textual.